# How to securely load SQL fixtures in Django

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, bandit-python

I have some fixtures of models in my code base for easy initial setup of the project. However, it includes `SQL` fixtures as well which means `.sql` files.

I have looked deeply in Django `loaddata` but it does not support 'SQL' fixtures because,

> sql is not a known serialization format

So, I tried to load data directly from MySQL using `mysql --host={host} --port={port} --user={user} --password={password} {database} < {filename}` command.

But I have lots of `sql` files and I do not want to load each file individually, so I decided to add a script to load all sqls files from specified directory and run above command using `os.system`.

And now **[bandit](https://pypi.org/project/bandit/)** is giving security warning for it

> Issue: [B605:start_process_with_a_shell] Starting a process with a shell, possible injection detected, security issue.
>   Severity: High   Confidence: High

So I am looking for a secure way to load data from SQL files.